# How to prevent a user responding to a survey a second time in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, survey, sharepoint-online

My aim is to allow users to respond to a survey only once.

They can login to page and view it but cannot submit another response.

Can anyone suggest how to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

Is that a "survey" survey or a custom list? In a regular survey, just tick the box for "no" when answering the question "Allow multiple responses".

For a list you need to inject the list form with Javascript that queries the current list entries' CreatedBy field and compares it to the current user. If a match is found, take appropriate action.

You will probably want to use jQuery and SPServices for that, so you don't have to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: This is survey if i allow multiple responses to yes then users can respond survey second time also but i dont want to do that users can see the page but cannot select second time......... we cannot assume which user will select the items then how can we use created by in the list

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. If you don't want to allow multiple responses, then tick "no" in the option. That's how it works out of the box. If you need something different, then you'll have to use a custom list and put in some more work yourself, as I explained above.

Comment: Hi Teylyn, the user submit respond only once,but They can visit survey page and view it but cannot submit another response.

Comment: build a page with a webpart that shows the survey without the "Add New" link, so people who have already completed the survey can visit that page instead of the survey start page.